# Combining certain columns of several tab-delimited files based on first column

Tags: awk, merge, csv

1st column in inFile contains a string not necessarily present in all inFiles

2nd and 7th columns in each inFile contains the Title# strings

Using AWK, I cannot piece this together correctly. My use of descriptive variables will hopefully help clarify what I'm trying to do. These are components I think I need:

1. tab-separated input files:  `-F'\t'`
2. increment the strings in the 1st column, but only add each 'name' once to the '1stColumnNames': `!1stColumnNames[$1]++ { name[++i] = $1 }`
3. make a new index for each .tsv file to store values for each file to avoid overwriting each column's values: `!r[FILENAME]++ { ++argind }`
4. store corresponding column values in 2nd and 7th columns for each file: `{ 2ndColumnVals[$1, argind] = $2 } { 7thColumnVals[$1, argind] = $7 }`
5. print all 1stColumnNames with associated 2ndColumnVals and 7thColumnVals, including their headers 'Title1' 'Title2' 'Title3' etc. : `?????`
6. index values that were empty for a particular 2ndColumnVals or 7thColumnVals, print as Mtee: `?????`
7. do this for all .tsv files in the current working directory and ouput a new tsv file: `*.tsv > outFile.tsv`

## Example Files

#### inFile1.tsv

```
Names   Title1  Title2
AAAA    1111    123456
BBBBB   1111    123456
CCC     1111    123456
```

#### inFile2.tsv

```
Names   Title3  Title4
BBBBB   2222    789456
DDDDD   2222    789456
EEEE    2222    789456
```

#### inFile3.tsv

```
Names   Title5  Title6
AAAA    3333    987654
CCC     3333    987654
EEEE    3333    987654
```

#### outFile123.tsv

```
Names   Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6
AAAA    1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654  
BBBBB   1111    123456  2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
CCC     1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654
DDDDD   Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
EEEE    Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  3333    987654
```

## Test Script

GNU Awk 4.0.1 is located in /usr/bin/awk , so I made this file and executed it in the same working directory where the 3 input files are located:

named as script1.sh

```
#### Example Usage:  script1.sh inFile1.tsv inFile2.tsv inFile3.tsv > outFile123.tsv

awk -F'\t' '
FNR==1 { ++numFiles}
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ a[$1,numFiles] = $2 FS $3 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=numFiles;fileNr++) {
            printf "\t%s", ((key,fileNr) in a ? a[key,fileNr] : "Mtee\tMtee")
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' "$@"
```

Running `awk -F script1.awk inFile1.tsv inFile2.tsv inFile3.tsv > outFile123.tsv` prints the follow error messages:

`awk: cmd. line:1: inFile1.tsv`

`awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error`

## Test Script 2 from konsolebox

### works perfectly but I'm trying to understand each line by commenting:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#### named as script2.awk
#### Example Usage:  awk -f script2.awk inFile1.tsv inFile2.tsv inFile3.tsv > outFile123.tsv

BEGIN { FS = "\t" } #input File Style is tab-delimited
{ sub(/\r/, "") }   #remove all carriage return characters
!f[FILENAME]++ { ++indx }   #for all files inputted make a single index called indx
!a[$1]++ { keys[i++] = $1 } #the new indx comprises only unique strings in column 1
{ b[$1, indx] = $2 FS $3 }  #the 2nd and 3rd column are tab delimited and each pair that corresponds to a string saved in keys gets stored after the 1st column string in matrix b
END {
    for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) {   #????
        key = keys[i]   #????
        printf "%s", keys   #prints out all strings in the index column 1 stored as keys
        for (j = 1; j <= indx; ++j) {   #????
            v = b[key, j]   #????
            printf "\t%s", length(v) ? v : "Mtee" FS "Mtee" #print out strings as tab delimited and replace any lengths of 1 char to two Mtee separated by a tab
        }
        print ""    #????
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a clear description, testable input/output, and having put effort into solving it yourself!

Comment: `script1.awk` is NOT an awk script, it is a shell script which calls awk. Rename it to `script1.sh` for clarity, make it executable just like any other shell script, add `"$@"` to the end of the awk script so shell passes awk it's argument list, and then execute it as `script1.sh inFile1.tsv inFile2.tsv inFile3.tsv > outFile123.tsv`. I edited your question to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's another `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Set field separator to tab (\t)
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
# Remove carriage return characters if file is in DOS format (CRLF)
{ sub(/\r/, "") }
# Increment indx by 1 (starts at 0) everytime a new file is processed
!f[FILENAME]++ { ++indx }
# Add a key ($1) to keys array every time it is first encountered
!a[$1]++ { keys[i++] = $1 }
# Store the 2nd and 3rd field to b matrix
{ b[$1, indx] = $2 FS $3 }
# This block runs after all files are processed
END {
    # Traverse the keys in order
    for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) {
        key = keys[i]
        # Print key
        printf "%s", key
        # Print columns from every file in order
        for (j = 1; j <= indx; ++j) {
            v = b[key, j]
            printf "\t%s", length(v) ? v : "Mtee" FS "Mtee"
        }
        # End the line with a newline
        print ""
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
Names   Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6
AAAA    1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654
BBBBB   1111    123456  2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
CCC     1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654
DDDDD   Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
EEEE    Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  3333    987654
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! The Usage is particularly helpful at addressing my error on running the script.

Comment: @BlacquenedRed This is a different answer.

Comment: This works beautifully, but I'm trying to understand it. 'b' is a matrix you made and the indx inside is tab-delimited col 2 and col 3?

Comment: indx is a counter that increments on every file so it starts as 1 in file then goes to 2 on file2 and so on..

Comment: Is there a better resource than http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#SEC_Contents ? I added yours above as script2.awk and tried commenting what I understand but unsure

Comment: @BlacquenedRed It's my best reference. I haven't tried any other material for `awk`. A quick reference also is `man gawk`. I do `/something` at the beginning to search for something quick.

Comment: In `(i = 0; i in keys; ++i)`, loop starts with `i` set to `0`. Loop continues while `i in keys` is valid. `i in keys` is valid if keys has an index set with the value of `i` e.g. it's valid if `i = 1` and `keys[1]` is set. `++i` increments `i` by 1 before the loop restarts.

Answer (score 4):

You need something like this:

Gawk version (for ARGIND plus true 2D arrays in gawk 4.0+):

```
$ gawk -F'\t' '
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ a[$1][ARGIND] = $2 FS $3 }
END {
    for (keyNr = 1; keyNr <= numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr = 1; fileNr <= ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "\t%s", (fileNr in a[key] ? a[key][fileNr] : "Mtee\tMtee")
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' file1 file2 file3
```

Non-gawk version:

```
awk -F'\t' '
FNR==1 { ++numFiles}
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ a[$1,numFiles] = $2 FS $3 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=numFiles;fileNr++) {
            printf "\t%s", ((key,fileNr) in a ? a[key,fileNr] : "Mtee\tMtee")
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' file1 file2 file3
Names   Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6
AAAA    1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654
BBBBB   1111    123456  2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
CCC     1111    123456  Mtee    Mtee    3333    987654
DDDDD   Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  Mtee    Mtee
EEEE    Mtee    Mtee    2222    789456  3333    987654
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment Ed! I can't get it to run properly though and this is the file I have saved:  


#!/usr/bin/gawk
#####save and run as ./test.sh
gawk -F'\t' '
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ a[$1][ARGIND] = $2 FS $3 }
END {
    for (keyNr = 1; keyNr <= numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr = 1; fileNr <= ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "\t%s", (fileNr in a[key] ? a[key][fileNr] : "Mtee\tMtee")
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' inFile1.tsv inFile2.tsv inFile3.tsv

Comment: In what way does it "not run properly"? Wrong output, no output, core dump, error message - what? Also, you can't include formatting in comments so update your question if you have code or other formatted text to show us. Finally - run `gawk --version` and post the result, you need gawk 4.0 or later for true 2D arrays and many other very useful features.

Comment: Error in Line 1 of my test.sh (where gawk is located) seems to be an issue. $ which gawk  does return the location /usr/bin/gawk. Darn, I just edited/updated before seeing you modify it to just awk, I'll try again.

Comment: I see you posted it. Just delete the first line `#!/usr/bin/gawk` as that tells the shell to run gawk on the script, but then the first line (`gawk -F...`) is a shell command, not an awk command. You either need a shebang (`#!..`) followed by JUST the body of an awk script, or no shebang and then a shell script which calls awk but you can't have both. I personally usually find the no shebang approach easier to work with.