# Combining certain columns from multiple files based on a particular column , and not eliminating duplicate names

Tags: awk

I had to combine values of 2nd columns from multiple files, based on the 7th column of all files, so based on Ed Morton's answer in similar question ([Combining certain columns of several tab-delimited files based on first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046526/combining-certain-columns-of-several-tab-delimited-files-based-on-first-column)) , I wrote code like this :

```
awk 'FNR==1 { ++numFiles}
!seen[$7]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $7 }
{ a[$7,numFiles] = $2 } 
END {
for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
     key = keys[keyNr]
     printf "%s", key
     for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=numFiles;fileNr++) {
         printf "\t%s", ((key,fileNr) in a ? a[key,fileNr] : "NA")
     }
     print ""
 } } ' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > combined.txt
```

INPUT FILE 1 :

```
+-------+-----------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  ID   | adj.P.Val_file1 | P.Value  |      t      |    B     |    logFC    | Gene.symbol |
+-------+-----------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 36879 | 1.66E-09        | 7.02E-14 | -12.3836337 | 21.00111 | -2.60060826 | AA          |
| 33623 | 1.66E-09        | 7.39E-14 | -12.3599517 | 20.95461 | -2.53106808 | AA          |
| 23271 | 2.70E-09        | 2.30E-13 | -11.8478184 | 19.93024 | -2.15050984 | BB          |
|    67 | 2.70E-09        | 2.40E-13 |  -11.829044 |   19.892 | -3.06680932 | BB          |
| 33207 | 1.21E-08        | 1.35E-12 | -11.0793461 | 18.32425 | -2.65246816 | CC          |
| 24581 | 1.81E-08        | 2.41E-12 | -10.8325542 | 17.79052 | -1.87937753 | CC          |
| 32009 | 3.25E-08        | 5.05E-12 | -10.5240537 | 17.11081 | -1.46505166 | CC          |
+-------+-----------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

INPUT FILE 2 :

```
+-------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  ID   | adj.P.Val_file2 | P.Value  |      t     |     B     |    logFC   |  Gene.symbol |
+-------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 40000 | 5.43E-13        | 1.21E-17 |  17.003819 | 29.155646 |  2.4805744 | FGH          |
| 32388 | 1.15E-11        | 5.12E-16 |  14.920047 | 25.829874 |  2.2497567 | FGH          |
| 33623 | 6.08E-11        | 4.43E-15 |   -13.8115 | 23.870549 | -2.8161587 | ASD          |
| 25002 | 6.08E-11        | 5.40E-15 |  13.713018 | 23.689571 |  2.2164681 | ASD          |
| 33207 | 2.03E-10        | 2.29E-14 | -13.009752 |  22.36291 | -2.8787392 | ASD          |
| 13018 | 2.03E-10        | 2.71E-14 |  12.929201 | 22.207038 |  3.0181585 | ASD          |
|  5539 | 2.24E-10        | 3.48E-14 |  12.810902 | 21.976634 |  3.0849706 | ASD          |
+-------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

DESIRED OUTPUT :

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Gene.symbol | adj.P.Val_file1 | adj.P.Val_file2 |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| AA          | 1.66E-09        | NA              |
| AA          | 1.66E-09        | NA              |
| BB          | 2.70E-09        | NA              |
| BB          | 2.70E-09        | NA              |
| CC          | 1.21E-08        | NA              |
| CC          | 1.81E-08        | NA              |
| CC          | 3.25E-08        | NA              |
| FGH         | NA              | 5.43E-13        |
| FGH         | NA              | 1.15E-11        |
| ASD         | NA              | 6.08E-11        |
| ASD         | NA              | 6.08E-11        |
| ASD         | NA              | 2.03E-10        |
| ASD         | NA              | 2.03E-10        |
| ASD         | NA              | 2.24E-10        |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

The problem is that the 7th column has repetitive names, and the code takes the first occurrence of a particular name, I want the results for all the repetitive names. I tried deleting each line of the code and understand, but couldn't come up with solution

Comment: Kindly post sample input and expected output, so that it will be useful for readers.

Comment: I hope the above example will help, the columns of the file is tab seperated , but when i want to represent tab seperated by pressing tab , it would open the tags dialogue box , so please consider the above example . the first and second file has same coloumn  headers , namely : ID ,  adj.P.Val_file1 ,  P.Value ,  t ,  B ,  logFC ,  Gene.symbol       whereas desired output file should only have :                       Gene.symbol ,  adj.P.Val_file1 ,  adj.P.Val_file2

Comment: Not sure where rows 8 and 9 come from in your expected output ?

Comment: Oh ! so row 8 and 9 should be FGH and FGH . Sorry that was a mistake, and thanks a lot Ian kenny for pointing me out the mistake and editing and present my input and desired files, I have correctd them now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining certain columns of several tab-delimited files based on first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046526/combining-certain-columns-of-several-tab-delimited-files-based-on-first-column)

Comment: Well i have already mentioned that i wrote code based on that , and the problem is it only considers the first occurence !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out answer by myself !

I just have to eliminate the line : ***!seen[$7]++*** from my code , as by including that it would only consider the first occurrence of any replicated name of 7th column (nth column in general)